# Flutter Search Button in app bar to a new page with TabBar items as option

Tags: flutter, search, tabbar

I'm just passing an Android application to Flutter, the current problem is as follows:
In Android I have a Fragment with a search button when the search button is clicked, a new fragment is shown with a tab layout where the user can search a book by title or by the user name, the aspect is shown in the next pictures:

[image]

In the new fragment, the user can choose the search by and can previsualize the matching results.

[image]

Which is the best way to implement something like this in Flutter, I understand that the beginning is something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Page Content 
      ],
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(this.text),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.search)
        )
      ],
    ),
);
```

But how I should implement the tab bar to choose the search by and the search input text in the app bar to be focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this onPressed function

```
onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
  );
          },
```

now create a new state class

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: TextField(),
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [Text("Books"), Text("Users")],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.search)
        )
      ],
    ),
));
```

Comment: Mohamed this worked, now How i should implment the search action if I have a list for each tab option in the tap bar? I tried to explain it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392702/how-to-implement-the-search-action-for-each-tab-in-tabbar

Comment: Sure, I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

```
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Page Content 
      ],
    ),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(this.text),
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [Text("Books"), Text("Users")],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.search)
        )
      ],
    ),
);
```